# async/await clarity, with sleep example

Tags: typescript, async-await, mocha.js, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to get hang of async/await with below implementation but it is not working as expected

```
    public static async sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
        await Utilities._sleep(ms);
    }

    private static _sleep(ms: number): Promise<{}> {
        return new Promise((resolve: Function) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
```

`_sleep` will resolve promise after n milliseconds, and await should `sleep` till that time..

but below test of mine is failing

```
it("should sleep for 500 ms", ()=> {
    const date1 = (new Date()).getTime();
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    const date2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    chai.expect(date2 - date1).to.least(500);
})
```

with message

```
 sleep should sleep for 500 ms FAILED
    AssertionError: expected 2 to be at least 500
```

my understanding was: `sleep` will await till the promise from `_sleep` is resolved (which as per setTimeout will resolve after 500ms)

**EDIT**

the test framework in `mocha`

Comment: You never await the result in your test when you call `Utilities.sleep(500);` See https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/923

Comment: `async` function is just a function that returns a promise. Calling it won't magically turn asynchronous code into synchronous. It's not clear what the question is. Is it about async function or tests? If the former, then test example is irrelevant. If the latter, then the question is lacking, it doesn't even mention which testing framework you use. So is it about testing or about async/await?

Comment: @estus I know its not magic, and hence trying to learn something which I dont understand. the question is about implemention `sleep` in javascript

Comment: It might be worth noting that your `sleep()` method adds no value over `_sleep()`. They both return a promise that resolves after `ms` milliseconds and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @user3432422 great point, thanks a lot for that info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not waited for your `sleep()` call (as described by the user @igor in the comments of your question):

Simplified version:

```
async function sleep(ms: number) {
    await _sleep(ms);
}

function _sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

console.time('start')
sleep(500).then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('start')
})

// If your test runner supports async:
it("should sleep for 500 ms", async () => {
    const date1 = (new Date()).getTime();
    await sleep(500);
    const date2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    chai.expect(date2 - date1).to.least(500);
})
```

Comment: but I had await in `sleep`, how is that different from await in `test`

Comment: You need to also await for `sleep(500)` when you call it.

Comment: added `await` also in test (await Utilities.sleep(500)), but that is also not working.

Comment: Maybe your test runner doesn't support async?

Comment: @unional This is what happens when poor questions are answered, they result in poor answers. The OP haven't specified testing framework and stated that it's not important, but of course, it matters.

Comment: @estus it is not that bad, I already made the disclaimer that "if the test runner support async". :)

Comment: Probably it should be noticed in the answer that it applies to Mocha (there's no such thing as async function support, but Mocha supports promise returns).

Comment: It can also be `jest`, which has the same syntax

Answer (score 2):

Only `await` awaits, and at the *call-site*. `await` is also only valid *inside* `async` functions. Usage:

```
await promise;
```

Think of an `async` function as just a better way of writing a function that returns a promise. It's just syntactic sugar.

It's not possible to hide asynchronous semantics nested inside synchronous function calls, without changing the semantics of all the functions calling it, making them all async. Consider whether things return in this run of the event loop or later.

If you wonder why async semantics isn't the default, read [why co-routines won't work on the web](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/).