# How to pause a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, async-await, sleep

How can I add a pause in this function, so that the value of 'datasum' changes every 2 seconds?

```
i:number; datasum:number; sum:number;
startCalculating(_i,_sum) 
{
 _i=1; _sum=0;
 while(_i<100)
 {
  _sum=_sum+2;
  this.datasum=_sum;
  _i=_i+1;
 }
}
```

I have already tried the methods suggested in: 
[pausing-in-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160542/how-to-pause-a-recursive-function-for-3-seconds-in-javascript), [typescript-sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764665/typescript-sleep) and [async/await-in-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181788/async-await-clarity-with-sleep-example).
Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618496/simple-countdown-timer-typescript/51618573#51618573

Comment: Yes it does, thanks!

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764665/typescript-sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to use the `async/await` pattern, and in your `while` loop you can await for a `Promise` that gets resolved after 2 seconds.

Something like this:

```
function delay(timeInMillis: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeInMillis));
}

class YourClass {
  datasum = 0;

  async startCalculating(): Promise<void> {
    let _i = 0;
    let _sum = 0;
    while (_i < 100) {
      _sum += 2;
      this.datasum = _sum;
      await delay(2000);
      _i += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

For clarity, I tried to keep the code as similar as possible to your own.